# Increment a VERSION ID by one and write to .mk file

Tags: python

I have code to read in the version number from a make file.

```
VERSION_ID=map(int,re.match("VERSION_ID\s*=\s*(\S+)",open("version.mk").read()).group(1).split("."))
```

This code takes VERSION_ID=0.0.2 and stores it as [0, 0, 2].

Is there any way I can increment this number by one and write the new version number into the version.mk file with the variable VERSION_ID.

Thanks

I have tried the same statement with write() instead of read() but I am getting an error saying that I can not write a list. I have also tried to write it as a string but am getting a bad file descriptor message.

```
s = str(VERSION_ID)

VERSION_ID=map(int,re.search("VERSION_ID\s*=\s*(\S+)",open("version.mk").write(s)).group(1).split("."))
```

I know this is rubbish, I just can't seem to find what to do here in the online docs.

I have also tried the pickle module to no avail. Maybe I'd be able to write a pickled list instead and then unpickle it. Or I was thinking I could just write over the whole line altogether.

I've tried to do anther approach, Ihave tried to get list to be entered as a string. I have tried this but I am not sure if it will work.

```
for x in VERSION_ID:
    "VERSION_ID={0}.{1}.{2}.format(x)
```

Comment: Ahhh.... Send this to "pleaseDoMyWorkForMe.com".  They like these kind of questions.

Comment: There are many ways to it, what specific problems are you having? What have you tried that did not work for you?

Comment: @ S.Lott, I am not trying to get my work done for me, I have tried to read the answers myself and can't find them. I am starting to learn Python and programming at a certain level.

When I learn how to program in python I will not ask as many stupid questions. If you have nothing constructive to say please don't comment at all.

Comment: @chrissygormley:  Please be careful of your questions.  Your initial question was way, way off base for Stack Overflow.  Your explanation is helpful.  Your question should reflect what you've actually tried and what question you actually have.  SO sees dozens of "domyworkforme.com" questions every day.  Yours looked exactly like those.  If you have *specific* information needs, please ask *specific* questions.  Your revised question is much better.  My comment's purpose is to help you write a better question.

Comment: @S.Lott, alright, that's fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhpas something like this (you should also check for errors and that)

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import re

fn = "version.mk"
omk = open(fn).readlines()
nmk = open(fn, "w")
r = re.compile(r'(VERSION_ID\s*=\s*)(\S+)')

for l in omk:
    m1 = r.match(l)
    if m1:
        VERSION_ID=map(int,m1.group(2).split("."))
        VERSION_ID[2]+=1 # increment version
        l = r.sub(r'\g<1>' + '.'.join(['%s' % (v) for v in VERSION_ID]), l)
    nmk.write(l)
nmk.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Genius, that works perfectly, I don't know what I was at.